# How to pass data from function in activity to a Notifcation Receiver Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

*How do you correctly pass data from one activity to another which extends BroadcastReceiver?*
I'm trying to pass two strings from a callNotification function to a NotificationReceiver activity. I call my function 10 minutes before a class starts to let a user know which lecture they have and in which lecture theatre.
This is what I place to transfer the two strings in my function:

```
Intent intentNotif = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    intentNotif.putExtra("MODULE", module10 );
    intentNotif.putExtra("LOCATION", location10 );
    startActivity(intentNotif);
```

However, in my NotificationReceiver activity, I'm told that the method getIntent cannot be resolved. Am I calling the intent properly in my activity?

```
Intent intentNotif = getIntent();
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("MODULE");
    String t = getIntent().getStringExtra("LOCATION");
```

This is my function:

```
 public void callNotification(int hour, int min, int sec, String module10, String location10 ){
    //new NotificationReceiver(id);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);

    //String extra = module + " - " + location;
    Intent intentNotif = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    intentNotif.putExtra("MODULE", module10 );
    intentNotif.putExtra("LOCATION", location10 );
    startActivity(intentNotif);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intentNotif,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    //RTC_WAKEUP makes sure that the alarm will be triggered even if the device goes into sleep mode
    //calendar.getTimeInMillis() will be the time that we want the alarm to go off at
    //alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY is the interval, how often it should get called, INTERVAL_DAY makes it show up on a daily basis
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}
```

This is my NotificationReceiver Activity:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//int notify_id = 100;
//MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
//int id = obj.notify_id;

//int id = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     //onReceive will always get called when the class ges triggered
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); // provides an builder interface to create an Notification object.
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);    //When the notification is pressed, it will open ReceivingNotification
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   //FLAG..TOP means that if MainActivity is already open when the notification is pressed, it will close it and freshly open it again
    //String text_notif = intent.getStringExtra(Monday.MONDAY_KEY);
    //if we want ring on notifcation then uncomment below line//
    //Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    //Pending intent specifies action performed when user clicks notifcation

    Intent intentNotif = getIntent();
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("MODULE");
    String t = getIntent().getStringExtra("LOCATION");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).

            setContentIntent(pendingIntent).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).
            setContentText("You have Module"+s+"in Theatre"+t).
            setContentTitle("My notificaton - id " + String.valueOf(100)).
            addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Next module", null).
            //setSound(alarmSound).
                    setAutoCancel(true);    //This makes the notification dismissable when the user hits it away


    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    //notify_id++;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already receive an `intent` in your `onReceive` method, you do not need to call `getIntent()`.

Instead of:

```
Intent intentNotif = getIntent();
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("MODULE");
String t = getIntent().getStringExtra("LOCATION");
```

Try with:

```
String s = intent.getStringExtra("MODULE");
String t = intent.getStringExtra("LOCATION");
```